# List is not getting binded

Tags: sapui5

I am not able to bind the data to List. Tried couple of ways - binding directly in the view also using read method in the onInit method of controller.
Please assist.

View code:

```
 var oList = new sap.m.List({
        type:sap.m.ListType.Navigation,
        id : this.createId("qList"),
        template: listItems
    });

    var listItems = new sap.m.ActionListItem({
           text:"{Quarter}",
           id : this.createId("Q1"),
           type:sap.m.ListType.Navigation,
           press:function(){
            oController.quarterSelect();
        }});
    oList.bindItems("fullmodel>/ETQUARTERSet", listItems);
```

Controller code:

```
 onInit: function() {
    this.router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("http://dewdfcto021.wdf.sap.corp:1080/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZOC_SERVICES_SRV/");
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"fullmodel");

    var quartersList = this.byId("qList");
    var quarterItem = this.byId("Q1");


    var pathFilterCond = "/ETQUARTERSet";
    oModel.read(pathFilterCond, null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse)
            {
                if (oData)
                    {
                    var oJSONQuarters = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
                    quartersList.setModel(oJSONQuarters);
                    quartersList.bindAggregation("items", "/Quarter", quarterItem);
                    }
            }

    );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you're using a named model, the name of the model should be prefixed in every binding path. You're missing out the model name when you bind text of the listItem.

```
var listItems = new sap.m.ActionListItem({
           text:"{fullmodel>Quarter}",
           id : this.createId("Q1"),
           type:sap.m.ListType.Navigation,
           press:function(){
            oController.quarterSelect();
        }});
```

oList.bindItems("fullmodel>/ETQUARTERSet", listItems);